# React Native: All styles in StyleSheet object after exporting were converted to number type

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My style object: `mainModule/styles.js`

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 0
  },
  basicInfo: {
    height: 167,
    backgroundColor: 'red,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
}
```

When I importing `import generalStyle from '@mainModule/styles'` (I created a `package.json` file to make that path works)
And the **console log** shows like this:

**Object {
  container: 10,
  basicInfo: 118
}**

Could anyone here can help me?

Comment: what does your `console.log` statement look like?

Comment: As far as I know, RN caches the StyleSheet objects and refers to the cached properties with id numbers. But if you want to import properties, do them as plain objects and convert to StyleSheet object inside the target file.

Comment: I just used `console.log(generalStyle)`.
Could you guide me more detail? I don't get what you mean `do them plain objects & convert to StyleSheet object inside the target file`.

Comment: try `flatten` method: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/stylesheet.html#flatten

Comment: Thanks Cherniv but `flatten` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

@NellyNgo, you probably trying to flatten the  whole object that `StyleSheet.create`  returns. I did the  same and it was driving me crazy, because it seemed to work for everyone else but for me returned the  same value that I've passed to it. Actually flatten will work for the separate property of the object that was created by `StyleSheet.create`. Like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({prop: {...}, prop2: {...})
```

and then you can do `StyleSheet.flatten(styles.prop)`

Check the  code in node_modules/react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/flattenStyle.js. that's the place where it failed for me.

```
 function getStyle(style) {
          if (typeof style === 'number') {
            return ReactNativePropRegistry.getByID(style);
          }
          return style;
     }
```

Check the whole source if interested

My RN version is 0.41.2

Answer (score 1):

`StyleSheet.create` creates style ids that are cached in order to reduce the amount of data that goes through the bridge.

You can use them and they will work perfectly, but if you need to alter them after importing, you should export the style object without `StyleSheet.create`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But could you guide me more detail? I'm a newbie with React Native.

Comment: This is exactly the warning that I'm facing
`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop styles of type number supplied to MyComponent, expected object.`

Comment: Where are you using this style as a prop? Share some code

Comment: I mean I define the `styles` prop for component `MyComponent` as an object and this will cause that issue (because all styles now are `number`).
Styles worked but the warning always show. I just want to find any way to refactor that code.

Comment: That's a whole new question than what you asked originally. I suggest you close this question since you got an answer. Open a new question with this new question and please add some code so we can help you. If we can't see `MyComponent` we won't know what problem it has.

Answer (score 1):

In **styles.js**:

```
const stylesObj = {
  container: {
    width: 0
  },
  basicInfo: {
    height: 167,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
}

export default stylesObj
```

And in the component:

```
import stylesObj from 'styles'

const styles = StyleSheet.create(stylesObj)
```

Comment: This is exactly the warning that I'm facing `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop styles of type number supplied to MyComponent, expected object.`.
So follow your solution, my issue still can't be solved.

Comment: I just tried this solution in RN and it worked as expected. So I don't know why your propTypes tend to fail.

Comment: I mean I defined the `styles` prop for component `MyComponent` as an object and this will cause that issue (because all styles now are `number`).
Styles worked but the warning always show. I just want to find any way to refactor that code.

Comment: Odd enough, this actually worked for me! None of the `Stylesheet.create` tricks/samples worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default YourStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 0
  },
  basicInfo: {
    height: 167,
    backgroundColor: 'red,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
}
```

then `import YourStyle from './YourStyle';`